# Add comments from the admin panel?

Tags: comments, post-editor

I'm using WordPress as an Authoring tool. Hence I do not use the front end.

Now I wanna add the functionality making internal comments. As it is now, you are only allowed to read comments from the Edit Post page, not to write them.

Got any hints or good ideas on how to make this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be possible in the upcoming version WordPress 3.4. Try the [Beta](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/) or just wait.

Here is a screen shot (incomplete translation to German):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use the plugin [Peter's Post Notes](http://www.theblog.ca/wordpress-post-notes) for something similar on one of my sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave comments on the actual post content, here is the solution I came up with a few weeks ago.

It is very similar to what toscho has posted, but works on the current stable WordPress release.

The code is set up for editor and admin capabilities, but can work for any role with a slight tweak of `current_user_can`

[How can I allow editors to leave comments on posts that have not yet been published?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/48731/14558)